# How to get FALSE NA get NA instead of FALSE

Tags: r, if-statement

I expect to get the following output in **R**:

> FALSE  NA     NA
>
> TRUE   NA     NA
>
> TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
>
> FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
>
> NA     NA     NA

I have tried working with this code:

```
ifelse(x&&y,TRUE,FALSE)
```

I get the correct answer in all cases except FALSE NA  gives FALSE instead of NA.

Comment: What language are you asking about?

Comment: @Brian I am using R

Comment: what is the INPUT and what is the OUTPUT you expect???

Comment: It's `x & y`, just **one** ampersand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this.

```
ifelse(is.na(x)|is.na(y),NA,x&y)
```

Comment: Thanks Andre. This is better ifelse(is.na(x|y),NA,x&y)

Comment: I think mine is more reliable. With T, NA you would go with an NA value to the ELSE statement. This could cause problems in other scenarios. However in that case you could use your slightly shorter version.